# Preventing Google Play Services autoinstallation into an ancient Android phone

Tags: google-play-services

How do I prevent Google Play Services from automatically installing now and then into a rooted Orange San Francisco aka ZTE Blade under a heavily trimmed down custom Android 2.3 ROM? Is the best way of achieving that described here?:
http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/240696-how-permanently-block-google-play-services-installing-automatically.html#post2649165

Please note: I clearly understand why I want it as such and why I want it exactly that way. Please refrain from responding with anything but exact answers. This particular phone under this particular ROM works exceptionally well w/o the app in question, including any Google service used.

Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: If this is a custom ROM, why does it comes with Google apps?

Comment: gapps.apk was enclosed with the ROM for those who want Google services, so I installed it afterwards to use Google Mail, Calendar etc.

Comment: I think that there is an option for this on the update screen of Google Play (at least in higher versions of Google Play) at the top. Is it still there in yours?

Comment: @seadoggie01: thank you - if there's a such option in yours would it be possible to upload a screenshot with it somewhere? I'll then check mine for the same option when I have it at hand again (it's my parent who uses it actually).

Comment: Sure! I actually went swimming with mine, but I'm waiting for a new one in the mail (should've been here 1 hour ago). I can do that as soon as I get it :D

Answer (score 0):

This is from Android 5.1.1 in Google play. The first picture is for only one app under the app and the stacked dots. The second picture is under Settings/Auto-Update apps. This obviously isn't the author's Android version, but you may want to see if there is a similar setting in your version.

[image: Auto-Update on individual app]
[image: Auto-Update all apps]

Comment: Thank you - do I get it right that the former one is a per-app setting? If so I'll have to have Google Play Services installed and just its updates blocked this way, right? If there's a really slim version of Google Play Services that'll probably work for me (the one that installs automatically grabs pretty much all remaining memory in that phone, so leaving it there is not an option). Meanwhile the latter option applies equally to all the apps, right?

Comment: Correct, the former is a per-app setting and the latter overrides all the apps